# Unable to perform New Database connection to `Dbeaver`, throws `Unable to load authentication plugin

Tags: mysql, node.js, dbeaver

Unable to perform New Database connection to `Dbeaver`, throws `Unable to load authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password'` Initially I have set a root user called `admin` and its password while setting the MySQl server which is different from below user `soccertest`
I have created soccertest user by running below query :

```
CREATE USER 'soccertest'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password BY 'somepassword';
```

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

I could see database available while running `mysql > show databases` from the command prompt

```
Server Host: localhost:
Port: 3306
Database: soccerreact
Username : soccertest
Password:  somepassword
Local Client: MySQL Server 8.0
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Try creating  with mysql_native_password option..

ALTER USER 'soccertest'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'somepassword';

Comment: I have run the above ALTER query as suggested and tried to connect to Dbeaver gives a new error,  Access denied for user 'soccertest'@'localhost' to database 'soccerreact'

Comment: hope you have granted access to read the database using 

Grant all privileges on soccerreact.*  to soccertest@localhost;
flush privileges;

Comment: That worked Ganesh, thank you very much for helping me out.

Comment: note, `flush privileges` is never needed on any standard user (CREATE|ALTER USER) or GRANT statement. It just comes into place when ugly hacks like manipulating mysql's tables directly occurs (which hopefully will be never needed again).

Comment: @soccerway add the same as answer so you can accept and close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating with mysql_native_password option..

```
ALTER USER 'soccertest'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'somepassword'; 

Grant all privileges on soccerreact.* to soccertest@localhost;
```